# Using wildcards with the bitap algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11, wildcard, fuzzy-search

I currently have an implementation of the bitap algorithm [here](http://pastebin.com/J5jZW2gq), but I'm wondering if there is a way to add wildcard support to it, using the array `ignoredPartsOfNeedle` which contains offsets starting from `haystackStart`, without gaining much time complexity.

For example:
`Haystack: abbsfe`
`Needle: abcd*f`
would return a fuzziness of 3 different letters rather than 4.

I have thought up a way to do this, but it requires modifying or inheriting from `std::map` which, AFAIK, is a Bad Thing and will lose portability because of the need to access private members of the map (Specifically `_M_t` for G++'s libstdc++)

Comment: The code is too long for me to go through and try to find out what it does. However, I can't see any reason why it would ever be necessary to derive from `std::map` and/or access a private member: can you explain why that would be needed?

Comment: Now that I think about it... I don't think it will work. The problem here is that I don't understand how the algorithm works, and if someone explains to me how it works, I will probably be able to work out a method myself.